# How to investigate and see what's going on under the hood during ISO installation?

Tags: installation, iso

Have looked around online for a while and haven't found anything on this topic.

How can I investigate what is going on during the installation of an ISO file?

I have been able to look at the components that an ISO file is composed of by running the xorriso utility to extract the components of the ISO, however how can I look at exactly what is going on when that ISO starts to install and complete the installation? The reason is because it seems like there is some "magic" going on where the installation creates files that did not exist before in the ISO.

Answer (score 0):

i assume you want to know about bootable ISOs which serve the purpose
to install an operating system from CD, DVD, or BD medium.

This procedure is standardized only at its beginning, when the boot
firmware of the computer looks for the entry points of boot software.

On BIOS and EFI firmware this is the El Torito Boot Record, stored
at block 17 of the ISO. This record points to the Boot Catalog, which
lists one or more Boot Images. A boot image for BIOS is a binary program
which gets loaded and executed by the BIOS. A boot image for EFI is a
FAT filesystem, which contains a binary program file which gets loaded
and executed.
(If the ISO is presented on a hard-disk-like device, BIOS looks for the
MBR signature at byte 510 and 511, and executes the x86 machine code
beginning at byte 0. EFI looks for a MBR partition of type 0xef or for
a GPT partition marked as EFI System Partition. These partitions point to
the same FAT filesystem as the El Torito boot catalog.)

In all these cases the executed program normally stems from a boot loader
system like ISOLINUX or GRUB. These boot loaders offer the opportunity
to start an operating system kernel which mounts the ISO filesystem
and executes programs from this filesystem.
In case of e.g. Debian GNU/Linux this is the DebianInstaller software.

These programs then constitute a running system which may install an
operating system to some disk device. In the course of this, files may
get unpacked from archives in the ISO, or generated by programs, or even
loaded from the internet.

So beginning by the menu configuration file of the boot loader, the
boot and installation procedure depends on particular software and
configurations.

Have a nice day :)

Thomas